# Vegan bean burrito?

Tags: veganism, food, recipe-request, beans

Is it possible to make a vegan bean burrito? If not how would it be possible to theoretically make one? I’m specifically am wondering about refried beans in the burrito.

Comment: Just leave out the cheese? It’s not hard. I’m not sure if this question is appropriate due to its trivial nature.

Comment: It's helpful if your question is focused -- for example, be specific about what ingredient you're having trouble substituting or removing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only is it possible, it's pretty easy!

Mexican food lends itself to being vegan with some simple substitutes because in a lot of recipes things like beans, rice, tomatoes, corn and other vegetables are the stars of the show rather than a side dish.

In a basic bean burrito recipe you'd probably only need to swap dairy cheese for vegan cheese.

There's lots of recipes out there for vegan bean burritos, such as [this one](https://www.vegkitchen.com/basic-bean-burritos/) or [this one](https://www.thespruceeats.com/vegetarian-bean-and-rice-burrito-recipe-3378550).

You could put lots of effort in to making things from scratch which I'm sure would be worth the effort, or you could just as easily use shortcuts to get something together quickly such as using a packet of microwave rice already made Mexican style, or using canned mixed or refried beans.

A few things I'd recommend:

- Using red or black rice rather than plain white rice because it has a nuttier flavour
- Add coriander (cilantro) leaves at the end before you wrap it up
- A little finely chopped sundried tomato for richer flavour
- A bit of lime juice if you're not adding guacamole